# apache rotatelog

Tags: php, apache, apache2, lamp

I am trying to figure what is wrong with the below directives

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  "||/usr/local/apache/bin/rotatelogs log/error.log 86400" 
CustomLog "||/usr/local/apache/bin/rotatelogs log/access.log 86400" combined

After changing to the above, apache server wouldnt start until i reverted back to a previous version that didnt use rotatelogs.

I checked the error log file but no error was logged, i knew the source of the problem but was hoping apache would log a specific error message to assist in debugging, also trying to figure why that didnt happen.

What I am trying to achieve, is have new log files created daily and the old logs archived. I read through the apache doc and this above is what i found as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **logrotate** utility as an alternative approach.